# Install Dedicated Server for CS:GO beta

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

In Steam, you can install the 'demo_viewer' beta for Counter-Strike: Global Offensive, which is basically an old version of CS:GO from 2013. I tried to install a dedicated server through steamcmd by using the -beta command line option, but it just installed the newest CS:GO version. Does anybody know how to install the beta on a dedicated server?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do/have you tried this? https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers

Comment: I know how to install a dedicated Server. But in Steam, you can right click CS:GO in your library, select "Properties" and then click the "Beta" tab. There you can select a Beta Version of the game.  I need to do the same for the server.